# How to Implement Cascading Object Properties in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have been tasked with doing the data mapping for a C# api, and it is one which features some more complex data relationships than I typically have had experience with (I have worked with foreign keys without data cascades, and have not validated data according to subclass before).

I am unsure of how to correctly institute the data mapping I have been tasked with - I could surely come up with something but I would rather not end up committing anti-patterns to the repo.

There is a parent class, let's say, Treat. All treats must have certain ingredients:

```
public class Treat 
{
    public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; }

    // Other members omitted
}

public class Ingredient 
{
    public Ingredient() { }

    // Other members omitted
}

public class Sugar : Ingredient 
{
    public Sugar() { }

    // Other members omitted
}
```

So let's say Treats are allowed to have (but don't have to) Sugar and Artificial Flavours only as ingredients. We define more ingredients for specific treats by referring to subclasses:

```
public class Chocolate : Treat 
{
    // Implementation omitted
}
```

Chocolate, let's say, can also have Cocoa : Ingredient and Flour : Ingredient.

How can I implement this mapping? I was going to store everything in columns of the one table and validate in the api endpoint controllers originally but I have been asked to reflect the validation rules in the class structure.

Comment: I do not quite understand your design of subclasses. There are mandatory and optional ingridients. Either the Mandatory/Optional is a boolean inside the base-class ingredient. Or Treat would have two lists of Ingredients: `MandatoryIngredients` and `OptionalIngredient` | By my understanding, a cascade would be if Chocolate could also be used as a Ingredient, while also being a Treat itself. But even for that, I have a solution.

Comment: All the code samples are classes, yet you mention columns and tables at the end. Is there a database involved?

Comment: Yes, we will be generating a database based on the models, probably with Entity Framework but not determined yet -- we are model first in any case.

Comment: From what you've described, it sounds like `Ingredient` should contain a `public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }` property. And it's not clear what purpose the `Treat` class serves (other than a "category name"). But it seems that, just as `Sugar` can be an `Ingredient` in `Chocolate`, `Chocolate` can be an ingredient in something else. And that something else may also have `Sugar` as an ingredient (like a Reese's Peanut Butter Cup). *AND* that something else may be a `Treat` (though this seems more like a category than a class).

Comment: Christopher - I think my use of "cascade" was incorrect. What is important is what is NOT an option rather than what is an option. For example, Chocolate : Treat may have cocoa as an ingredient, but Lollie : Treat may not. It may have Gluten as an ingredient but chocolate may not. etc....

Comment: The Treat class has other properties which are not relevant to this issue - for example, brands. We would be grouping treat brand over their type - It's Nestle -> Chocolate, not Chocolate -> Nestle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code only contains a N:M or Many to Many relationship. Every Treat (N) can have several Ingredients (M). But each ingredient (M) can also be used by several Treats (N). Those are very common, very standart problems. They can not be resolved really, only disolved into two smaler Problems.

On the DB side N:M Relationships are usually disolved into a N:1 and 1:N relationship, using a middle table (TreatIngridients). A table consisting of nothing but a Primary Key and two Foreign Keys. I am not sure how to implement a N:M on the class side, but it is a exceedingly common problem of code first. So I quickly found one link to EF:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Apparently both Clases will contain a List of their counterparts. This setup of cross references pains every programmer part of my brain (I hope I never get to do a OUTER JOIN on that. Keeping both lists in synch would be a nightmare). However it would be easily build from a Databse. You either build your Instances in Memory from the Ignredient side or the Treat side. The other will be mostly static data (with ingredients being propably usually the other side)